# Add GeoTrust image on checkout page in magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, payment-methods, credit-card

**I want to add GeoTrust secure image with credit card info images i cant found the file where i add it. Help if any one knows.**

[image]

Comment: i can recommend for example the chrome plugin for knockout js. It can show you the template file used by inspecting the element in the chrome dev tools